# Pandas data preserve using Read Excel Vs Read CSV

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

My excel file has data '0.24%', when i import this as dataframe using pandas read excel this value is converted as 0.0024, even after explicitly using the dtype as object\str and convert parameters.

Restored the same data in CSV format and read using padas read CSV, and now the attempt is successful. My data frame is '0.24%'.

Please note am using python 2.7 version. Please provide how to preserve the same data (value) using pandas read excel.

Comment: This might be a problem with how excel saves the data, in which case pandas is "preserving" the data, but the data is not what you think it is ("0.0024" instead of "0.24%")

Comment: I am reading data from excel. I want to retain the  as-is excel format in dataframe to perform some data comparison.

Comment: Please note parameters like dtype  as object and converters are not helping to preserve the as-is format of excel data.

Comment: Try to change the format of your excel data before reading it